# How to remove rows using regex with Dask?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dask

Is there a way to remove rows using a regex condition on a dask dataframe? I have a dask dataframe with about 100 million rows and I want to remove rows containing 'the ocean' in column B before I process it. Is there a way to accomplish it?

This is what the dataframe looks like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
"A":[34,12,78,84, 96], 
"B":['land', '', 'human', 'seagull by the ocean', 'running fox']
})
patternDel = '^.*THE OCEAN.*$'
filter = df['B'].str.contains(patternDel)
df = df[~filter]
```

But this does not seem to work in my case.

FYI: I cannot use pandas here since the data won't fit in the memory.

Comment: Looks like you are doing it right. Your dataset is huge. You probably need to chunk.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than complicating your implementation, you can simply use drop function of dataframe, provided by pandas library.
Please refer following link for usage.
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html

Comment: I cannot use pandas here since the data is large. 50Gigs.

Comment: There is no such limitation of reading large data size (~50GB) with pandas library. Still you can use parameter "chunk_size" to optimize your coding.